# Что необходимо для создания и работы с БД MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql-server

Здравствуйте.
Начал изучать БД. Скажите, пожалуйста, что мне необходимо иметь установленным? Установил SQL Server 2005 Express Edition, Management Studio. Этого достаточно чтобы создать БД? А если необходимо и создавать запросы, то где ихх писать, в установленном по дефолту SQLCMD.EXE? Вообще как лучше создавать БД (консоль или студия) и где писать запросы (консоль)? Работать предположительно надо в течении полугода исключительно для ознакомительных учебных целей. И нужен ли мне PHP Admin и что это?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вы установили SQL Server 2005 Express Edition - а это для работы с MS SQL, а не MySQL. Для работы с MySQL вам нужно установить MySQL Server (можно [отсюда](http://www.mysql.ru/download/))

Далее можно работать с бд просто из консоли, но удобнее будет установить какой-нибудь графический интерфейс, например, SQLyog, или можно установить phpMyAdmin - но это не обязательно, только для удобства работы.

Comment: извините, что не отписал сразу. Скажите тогда, какую лучше версию MySQL и PHPMyAdmin ставить на XP?

Comment: @MuscledBoy А зачем вам MySQL если уже есть MS SQL, у него возможностей побольше

Comment: @MuscledBoy, лучше всего последние, совместимые с вашей операционной системой

Comment: @Mike, я профан в этом - как видите. Скажите тогда создавать БД уже можно через студию и консоль?

Comment: @MuscledBoy, а что вы имеете в виду под словом "студия"?) Ну и просто через консоль вполне можно создать БД)

Comment: @Ksenia, видите появился коментарий, что уже не надо ничего устанавливать. Так я могу уже пробовать работать или нужен mysql. Кто прав?

Comment: @MuscledBoy, вы определитесь, c чем вы хотите работать - с MySQL или MS SQL. Так как это разные CУБД.

Comment: @Ksenia, я так понимаю, используя SQLCMD.EXE уже могу формировать запросы и создавать БД, а также можно создавать БД используя Manager studio?

Comment: @MuscledBoy, но тогда вы будете работать с MS SQL, а не с MySQL.

Comment: @MuscledBoy Раз Management studio установлен, то лучше им воспользуйтесь. он будет явно удобнее, чем sqlcmd

Comment: @MuscledBoy И да, конечно с БД надо определятся серьезно. Если у вас будут простенькие запросы, то они обычно смогут работать на любой СУБД. Но если что то более серьезное, то вы потом готовые запросы просто так не сможете перенести на другую СУБД ибо диалекты SQL у баз отличаются. А следовательно после написания проекта сменить СУБД в случае чего будет крайне тяжело

Comment: @MuscledBoy, вы можете создавать БД и через SQLCMD.EXE, и через Management Studio (и да, через второе удобнее) - но вы будете работать с MS SQL, а не MySQL

Comment: tl;dr: если вам нужен был MySQL, то **вы установили совсем не то, что вам надо**. Но если вы ещё не определились, есть смысл попробовать MSSQL (но быть готовым столкнуться с его коммерческой моделью).

Comment: Всем спасибо, буду разбираться

Comment: @Ksenia на самом деле удобнее работать из консоли, как правило. phpmyadmin  - идет лесом, изредка удобен, mysqlworkbench  очень полезен своим скиллом показывать синтаксические ошибки в запросе